# JPA @OneToMany cast collection to its size

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a piece of code with `School` entity that contains a list of its students (`List<Student> schoolStudents`). Is it possible to map this list to its size and have `Integer numberOfStudents;` entity instead? I tried to use `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas` with selecting count of students query but I'm always getting this exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.xyz.School.numberOfStudents
```

Here is an example of code:

School.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "school")
    private List<Student> schoolStudents = new ArrayList<Student>(); //desired: private Integer numberOfStudents;
```

Student.java

```
@JoinColumn(name = "schoolId")
private School school;
```

SchoolMapper.java

```
@Mapping(target = "students", source = "schoolStudents")
    SchoolDto schoolToSchoolDto(School school);

@Mapping(target = "schoolId", source = "school")
    StudentDto studentToStudentDto(Student source);
```

SchoolDto.java

```
public class SchoolDto {
    private String name;
    private List<Student> students; //desired: private Integer students;
}
```

StudentDto.java

```
public class StudentDto {
    private School school;
    private String studentName;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some details about `@Mapping` annotation. Where is it from?

Comment: it's from `org.mapstruct.Mapping`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant make field with count of related objects inside your entity.

What you can is to map it's size using expressions:

1. Create method returning size of students list

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<Student> schoolStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

   public int getStudentsCount() {
       return schoolStudents.size();
   }
   ```
2. Modify your DTO

   ```
   public class SchoolDto {
       private String name;
       private int students;
   }
   ```
3. Use expression inside your mapper

   ```
   @Mapping(target = "students", expression = "java(school.getStudentsCount())")
   SchoolDto schoolToSchoolDto(School school);
   ```

If your collection of students is large and you are concerned about performance\memory you can use annotation `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` but be careful because it may increase number of queries.